# Parsing and replacing Javascript identifiers with Rhino in Java

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Suppose I let the user to write a condition using Javascript, the user can write conditions to perform a test and return true or false. E.g.:

```
INS>5 || ASTO.valueBetween(10,210)
```

I want to find which variables are used in the script that the user wrote. I tried to find a way to get the identifier names in Java. The Rhino library didn't help a lot. However I found that via handling exceptions I could get all the identifiers. So this problem is solved.

So everything is great, but there is one little problem. How can I replace these identifiers with a numeric identifier? E.g. `INS` should be `_234` and `ASTO` should be `_331`.

`INS` and `ASTO` etc are entities in my database. I want to replace them, because the name may change. I could do it using a replace but this isn't easy because:

1. It should be reversible. E.g. `ASTO` to `_234` and `_234` to `ASTO` again.
2. Replacing `_23` with `MPLAH` may also replace `_234`. This could be fixed with regexp somehow.
3. What if `_23` is in a comment section? Rare to happen, but possible `/* _23 fdsafd ktl */`. It should also be replaced.
4. What if it is a name of a function? E.g. `_32() {}`. Also rare, but it shouldn't be replaced.
5. What if it is enclosed in `""` or `''`?

I am sure that there are a lot more cases. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having real trouble understanding your question. It really isn't too clear what you are doing.

Comment: Still too poor. I did an attempt to clarify it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parhs - what you really need is a JavaScript parser. Basically, you will be re-implementing pieces of Rhino although it's theoretically possible that Rhino already has hooks to do what you need (I'm not familiar with it so not sure); or you can extend Rhino since its source is 100% avialable from Mozilla. Another possible direction to look at is Google's GWT.

Comment: unluckilly i didnt provided much help...
Only extending source would be a solution